# Referencing classes in a Razor Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, namespaces, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-class-library

I created a new Razor Class Library (using "dotnet new razorclasslib").  I then created a folder called Models in the new library and it contains a class with the following test code:

```
using System;

namespace TestLibrary.Models
{
    public class TestModel
    {
        public string TestMethod { get; set; }
    }
}
```

However, when I try to use this class from the web application project (by referring to it as `TestLibrary.Models.TestModel`) I keep being told that the TestLibrary.Models namespace doesn't exist. The exact error is:

> The type or namespace name 'Models' does not exist in the namespace 'TestLibrary' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [TestApplication]

I'm assuming I'm missing something simple, just can't figure out what.

Comment: have you included your class lib in your web project as a dependency?

Comment: Yes, I have a ProjectReference entry in the csproj file.

Comment: tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution? preferably from VS

Comment: Yes, tried cleaning via the dotnet clean command.  Also tried manually deleting the bin and obj folders and then running dotnet restore.

Comment: if you have visual studio, try running the app on debugger. sometimes this cleans better than the `dotnet clean` command. and make sure the command is run for the whole solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was somehow related to the issue posted here: [Razor Class Library MSBuild MSB4062 Error During Compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53602506/razor-class-library-msbuild-msb4062-error-during-compile/53727591).  Once that was resolved this issue went away.